# Understanding surface charges on a resistor and what a voltmeter is measuring

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, potential, electrical-resistance, voltage

In this [video](https://youtu.be/bHIhgxav9LY?si=J1LAnmLEtJrmLUF_&t=265) Veritasium points out some misconceptions about electricty and hints at surface charges generating the actual electric field within the wires, better explained by Professor Carlson [here](https://youtu.be/Qp3iI06bujA?si=izZtdLB5q5U_Mhuy&t=560).

These explanations must lack some detail.

What I do not understand how surface charges can explain ohmian properties. Resistance itself is a concept better explained by something like the Drude or Sommerfeld model.
However it is a well known fact that voltage drops within resistances.

This leaves a big questions.
Imagine this simple circuit:

[image]

Let us assume that the voltage source is a battery containing an inner electrical field. The Integral of the E-Field over a connection between the both battery plates adds up to 5 volts.

Since the resistance is big enough all the voltage drops over it. This means that the gradient of the surface charges at the resistor must be strong enough to create a field which over the length of the resistor would result into a voltage of 5V.This does not make sense.

Following Kirchhoff's current law and the explanation of proportionality between the electric field $E$ and current density $j$ by something like Drude's model, the electric field must be same everywhere in the circuit including the resistor.

But this is not what gets measured by a volt meter. The voltmeter sees no change in voltage between the wires (no potential which gets lost), and then reports the full drop at the resistor.

Comment: A voltmeter measures the voltage through the metering device (!).

Comment: I get what you are saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the electric field must be same everywhere in the circuit including the resistor

This is incorrect. The electric field is not the same everywhere in the circuit.

> proportionality between the electric field E and current density j

This is in reference to Ohm’s law in “microscopic” form: $$\vec J = \sigma \vec E$$ where $\sigma$ is the conductivity. Note, even if $\vec J$ is constant, $\vec E$ will vary if $\sigma$ varies. Different materials have different $\sigma$. In fact, it is one of the material properties that varies the most. The wires have a much larger $\sigma$ than the resistor, so $\vec E$ is correspondingly larger in the resistor.

At the interface between the high $\sigma$ wire and the low $\sigma$ resistor, there is a discontinuity in the $\vec E$ field. It is small in the wire and suddenly becomes much larger in the resistor. Discontinuities in the $\vec E$ field occur where charges are located. This is a surface charge that is located at the surface between the two different materials.

As a side note: not all materials follow Ohm’s law, so there may be other reasons for $\vec E$ to vary, and Kirchoff’s current law says that $I$ is the same along a series circuit, not that $\vec J$ is the same.

Comment: I thought a bit about your answer. 

1. What if I make the change in material homogeneous, meaning I slowly start to increase the the percentage of material B and decrease A, then there is no such discontinuity. I could melt both materials together for example.

Comment: This is my follow up question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/798309/understanding-changes-in-surface-charge-distributions-between-high-and-low-sig