# Understanding changes in surface charge distributions between high and low $\sigma$ resistors and the relationsship to Drude's model

Tags: electrostatics, interactions

I am thinking about ohms relationship $E = j\sigma$, where $\sigma$ is entirely material-dependent, which can be explained by Drudes model and the common explanation that surface charges create the E-field inside a wire.

Imagine a high $\sigma$ wire and a low $\sigma$ resistor with same form and size (their area is the same) connected in a circuit with no other resistive element. Since $I = \int jdA$ and I is constant by Kirchhoffs first law, it follows that $E = j\sigma \implies \int E dA = \int j\sigma dA = \phi = I\sigma$ since A is constant and continuous. Thus $\phi$ and therefore $E$ must be different in the wire than in the resistor, otherwise $\sigma$ would be the same for the two materials.

In [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/790150/understanding-surface-charges-on-a-resistor-and-what-a-voltmeter-is-measuring) question the answer reads:

> At the interface between the high   wire and the low   resistor,
> there is a discontinuity in the ⃗   field. It is small in the wire
> and suddenly becomes much larger in the resistor. Discontinuities in
> the ⃗   field occur where charges are located. This is a surface
> charge that is located at the surface between the two different
> materials

But as much as I think about this answer, the more I doubt it. What would make surface charges "magically" know about the intrinsic properties of the resistors? Resistance is linked to Drude's model.

Can anyone provide accessible, practical evidence for this theory?

> This is a surface charge that is located at the surface between the
> two different materials

Lets say I transition slowly from material A to B, meaning there is no abrupt ending to material A. Instead I make a transition material where I slowy lower the percentage of material A and slowly heighten the percentage of B. Where are the surface charges now?

Comment: It is not magical. You are pushing electrons through the loop. As they traverse the loop, they will encounter the transition, and have more than enough information and time to reach a steady state. If you make this transition smooth, then there will be space charges.

Comment: I mean this sincerely: How do you know that where did you learn about it? It seems you just think it is bloody obvious (it is not) and I am dying to find a lecture, an article or a textbook with that phenomenon. Only textbook I know cost like 80$ which I do not want to spend for this single answer.

Comment: I am not at all claiming that it is obvious. It took graduate level classical electrodynamics, statistical thermodynamics and solid state physics before a deep understanding of what electrons are doing in wires can be understood. It is not at all simple to understand.

Comment: So basically electrical engineers cannot possibly expected to understand the fundamentals of the laws they are using? I constantly find myself doubting the laws I am applying and I usually start doubting circuits highschool students are confronting. Maybe I should just accept them.

Comment: Well, there are two solutions to that: 1) electricial engineers can take some physics if they wish to learn more. 2) The classical electrodynamics approximation, where you take some stuff like Ohm's Law on faith, or maybe Drude model on faith, is not too horrible. They are both plausible sounding and usually give good results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would make surface charges "magically" know about the intrinsic properties of the resistors?

There isn’t any magic about it. Electromagnetic fields can carry information. The materials simply respond at each moment according to their material properties and the local fields.

Recall that circuit theory assumes that the time scales of interest are much greater than the size of the circuit divided by the speed of light, meaning information is always available from the entire circuit. To see the information flow you must examine shorter time scales and therefore need to consider Maxwell’s equations rather than circuit theory.

Consider the scenario you described above in the instants after the switch is closed. Importantly, at the time scales we are considering, KCL is not valid and current is not uniform. The conductors begin initially with no internal charges.

The closing of the switch allows an EM wave to propagate through the conductors. To a first approximation we can consider this wave to be a step function, where in front of the wave the E field is 0 and behind it the E field has its final value. This is a simplification for didactic purposes to avoid messy wave reflections and interferences.

By Ohm’s law that implies that there is no current ahead of the wave and the final current behind the wave. The continuity equation in turn implies that charge accumulates at the front of the wave due to this non-uniform current.

As the charge accumulated at the front of the wave passes the junction between the materials, some of the charge will remain. If too much charge were to remain then the current would be too high in the second material which would remove the additional charge, and if too little charge were to remain then the current would be too low and additional charge would accumulate. Only the “right” amount of charge is consistent with the same amount of current in both materials.

> Lets say I transition slowly from material A to B, meaning there is no abrupt ending to material A. Instead I make a transition material where I slowy lower the percentage of material A and slowly heighten the percentage of B. Where are the surface charges now?

Then it is a volume charge in the bulk material. (Assuming that the conductivity is a gradual transition)

Comment: Thank you. I kind of get what you are saying, however, I would like to arrive at a deeper understanding. Can you suggest any textbook, lecture, video series?